# SQL sub query from PHP PDO query

Tags: php, sql-server

i have a question, i'm trying to execute a  MSSQL query from PHP, i executed the query directly in SQL SERVER and not problem, but if i execute the query from PHP PDO i don't get any result, testing the query without the sub query i got results without problems but if i do it with the sub query i don't get any result

The complete query is:

```
SELECT A.MATNR, B.MAKTX, C.EAN11, C.MEINH, C.HPEAN FROM FJBK.DBO.MARA AS A INNER JOIN FJBK.DBO.MAKT AS B ON A.MATNR = B.MATNR INNER JOIN FJBK.DBO.MEAN AS C ON A.MATNR = C.MATNR WHERE c.matnr = (select matnr from MEAN where ean11 = '.$articulo.')
```

if i execute the query in this way:

```
SELECT A.MATNR, B.MAKTX, C.EAN11, C.MEINH, C.HPEAN FROM FJBK.DBO.MARA AS A INNER JOIN FJBK.DBO.MAKT AS B ON A.MATNR = B.MATNR INNER JOIN FJBK.DBO.MEAN AS C ON A.MATNR = C.MATNR WHERE c.matnr = 1000256
```

i'm getting results.

i test the query a lot of times thinking that could be the PHP var in the query but isn't the problem

From PHP the sub query doesn´t return results, but directly in the MSSQL work without problems, i use this complete query in a Visual Basic.NET app and is working fine.

The problem is execute the subquery in the principal query from PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
where ean11 = '.$articulo.'
```

to

```
where ean11 = '\'.$articulo.'\')
```

or use double quotes to contain your sql and use

```
$sSQL = "SELECT A.MATNR, B.MAKTX, C.EAN11, C.MEINH, C.HPEAN
         FROM FJBK.DBO.MARA AS A
           INNER JOIN FJBK.DBO.MAKT AS B
             ON A.MATNR = B.MATNR
           INNER JOIN FJBK.DBO.MEAN AS C
             ON A.MATNR = C.MATNR
         WHERE c.matnr = (
           SELECT matnr 
           FROM MEAN 
           WHERE ean11 = '".$articulo."'
         )";
```

Comment: thanks my friend!! i had 2 days getting a headache trying to resolve this!! i used the double quotes and this resolved my problem! thanks a lot!!